# Whats the purpose of new in module.exports?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have a test broken into 3 components. The main page object Page, the page in question HomePage and the test itself.

I want `HomePage` to extend the `Page` object. However what I found is - if in the Page class I use:

`module.exports = new Page()`

I get the error `ERROR: Class extends value #<Page> is not a function or null`

however if i use

`module.exports = Page`

it works perfectly.

Could someone please explain why this is so? Is it because the Page object itself is only constructed with each of the pages its the parent of, e.g. `HomePage` or `LoginPage` or whatever other page?

```
class Page {
constructor() {
        this.title = 'My Page';
    }
    open(path) {
        browser.url('/' + path);
    }
}
module.exports = Page;
```

==

```
var Page = require('../page-models/Page');

class HomePage extends Page {
    get username()  { return browser.element('#username'); }

    open() {
        super.open('');
    }

}

module.exports = new HomePage();
```

== The test itself

```
var HomePage = require('../page-models/home.page');

describe('Something great', function(){

  it('tests this', function(){
    HomePage.open();
    ...
```

Any help appreciated.
p.s. using nodejs, webdriverio, mocha and chai.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you write:

```
var Page = require('../page-models/Page');
```

The variable `Page` is whatever you exported from '../page-models/Page' with `module.exports`. If you export a `new Page()` object then your variable `Page` will be that instance of the `Page` class you created with `new` not the class itself. And you can't `extend` an instance. Also,`require()` caches it's results so you always get the same object.

As you have it with `module.exports = Page` you export the class and anyone `require`-ing it is free to create their own instances as they see fit.

I know you didn't ask, but one thing to think about is creating a uniform interface with your classes. If you are going to export the `Page` class and ask users to instantiate or extend that class, you should consider doing the same for `Homepage`. Perhaps you might want to do something like:

```
var Homepage = require('../page-models/home.');
class MobileHomePage extends Homepage {
    //...
}
```

You can't do that it you export an instance with `new HomePage()`. This means you would need to create the instance in your test with something like:

```
var HomePageClass = require('../page-models/home.page');
var Homepage = new HomePageClass()
```

which is more verbose, but also makes your modules more flexible.